# How to check Native Messaging App already?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

I have an app using Native Messaging Technology, my app worked. I have a website, website communicating with extension, extension communicating with native app and feedback! I want to check my app is ready for work, I mean: How to my website can check native app already to work?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what the exact problem is. Your webpage sends a message to the extension, the extension will send a message to the native host, the host replies, the extension sends a message to the webpage, now the webpage knows everything's ok. If you want a specific answer then provide the actual code and other specifics in your question.

Comment: Your webpage sends a message to the extension, the extension will send a message to the native host, the host replies, the extension sends a message to the webpage, now the webpage knows everything's ok. => Yes, BUT It's ASYNCHRONOUS => I don't know exactly when native host replies! => So, Is there way I can check native host is already by SYNCHRONOUS? Thanks!

Comment: I can't even imagine how that might be possible without using the deprecated browser plugins like flash or java which don't work by default in modern Chrome.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to know that the extension is loaded vs. not present (and if loaded, to make sure all content scripts are loaded and in a ready state so that messages fired off from the webpage won't go into the ether). The recommended practice, I believe, is to have your content script create an element in the DOM when it's loaded and ready to go. Detecting this element's presence can be handled a number of ways, depending on your setup, but as I recently mentioned elsewhere, using a mutation observer can be handy to detect when it's added and removed.